# Filter dates on a store in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, filter, extjs4, datastore

I have a form with **4** datefields **(creation date start, create date ent, updated date start and updated date end)**.

In the form bottom, i have a **gridpanel** with a **column "Create Date"** and **other column "Updated Date"**.

I need to make a filter with the range of creation dates for column "create date" and another tolher to range for updated dates.

How i can make this comparison? Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Fill these variables from your form.
var createStart, createEnd, updateStart, updateEnd;

yourGridPanel.getStore().filter([
    {
        filterFn: function(item) {
            return (item.get('createDate') >= createStart) &&
                   (item.get('createDate') < createEnd);
        }
    },
    {
        filterFn: function(item) {
            return (item.get('updateDate') >= updateStart) &&
                   (item.get('updateDate') < updateEnd);
        }
    }
]);
```